# Did I solve my "Target class [mail.manager] does not exist." issue?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-7

Just upgraded from Laravel 6 to 7, and had the error response above when submitting a contact form. I eventually found a solution that seems to work and I am submitting here to help out the next guy.

In the terminal run:

```
composer require illuminate/mail
```

Add the following to the top of the controller file (app/Http/Controllers/Main.php in my case):

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

Add this to bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
```

Save and test, and it worked localhost.

If the above does not work for you, there are some other possible issues and solutions available at this link, where I must give credit to vipindasks.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/lumen-52-mail-not-working

Since I am suppose to ask a question:

Do you see any problems with this solution even though the site and mailer is working now?

Comment: Add a back slash `$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);`

Comment: For my own curiosity, why are you registering the provider there, and not in config/app.php?

Comment: @STA Done. Thank you.

Comment: @KurtFriars I just followed the ideas presented in the other link with some trial an error, and the site now works. I like what you are suggesting, but I messed around with some thing and could not figure it out.

Comment: Today I encountered this problem while upgrading my Laravel6 application to Laravel8, it turns out that all I have to do was `composer dump-autoload` *without* `--no-scripts` `--no-plugins` options after following official upgrade guide.  No need to tweak `bootstrap/app.php`, `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider` is staying in `config/app.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are simply missing a backslash. This tells the autoloader that the file you are looking for is not in the namespace your controller resides in :

```
$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Run composer update hope this will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake for me : call Mail facade inside `register()` method of the service provider...

It should rather be called inside its `boot()` method.